# Must a caught novice walk back to her cell even when passing out of sight?

Tags: nuns-on-the-run

In *Nuns on the Run*, when a novice has been caught by one of the guards, she must walk the shortest route back to her cell so long as the abbess or prioress can still see her.

My question is, must the novice complete her 'caught' movement honestly even if it takes her out of sight, or can the novice jink to the side as soon as there's a door between her and the guards?

Example: Ann Marie is caught two spaces from the south door to the chapel.  Her first two moves have to be south, but do her last one or two also have to be south, or can she turn and head into the garden?

Comment: Our group allows the novice to choose. If she stays 'caught', her token stays on the board even when she passes through a doorway but the head nun can't re-catch her and she automatically passes her noise checks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short terms, no.

When the honest movement takes you out of the guard's line of sight, you may then take the last one or two steps (since you are only walking) in your preferred direction.

In longer terms: I've interpreted the [rules](http://mayfairgames.com/mfg-shop3/rules/MFG4117-Rules-V1_0.pdf) literally. It says on page 3

> If you are caught by the guard, you are required to walk (not run) in the direction of your cell by the most direct route, **as long as you are visible to the guard**. Flip your novice status card over to "caught" as a reminder.